# How to find who registered the client in to the database?

Tags: php, database, session

I'm new to PHP, I'm making a system to register some clients, but the registration process is done by our admins in front of them, so the client doesn't touch the computer. So I need to know which admin registered the user after data added to the table in the database.

I have an admin login page and after admin logged in, it redirects to the client registration page. so I have one table for admins and another table for clients, again I need to know which admin registered them in the client table with the client's other information. I tried PHP sessions and, able to show which admin logged in. But I don't need to show it, I need to get that data to the client table.

check this image, I can see which admin logged in, on the website.
[image: check this image, I can see which admin logged in, on the website.]

here is the code I used to show which admin logged in

```
<div class="loggedin">welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?></div>
```

so now I need to get that PHP session data to the client table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a user management system to so that admin will always login with there credentials to use this software and when they registered new client you can save admin user details in database table

for example if you clienTable (ClientID, ClientName, RegistrationDate,.....,UserID)

UserTable(UserID, UserName,UserPrevilages,UserPassword,UserEmail,.....)

Depending on what you want to do you can manage it in the application as you will always know who is the admin user and save his UserId in ClientTable etc.. this way you will always know which user registered which Clients etc..

You can always store Admin userID in session variable of hidden field and use it whenever you want to.

Answer (score 1):

So all you have to do is to add a column in you user database table to store the admin who added the user. When you are running your `insert` statement (for registering new user), insert admin's name `$_SESSION['user']` in that column as well.